# How to get the version of Git programmatically?

Tags: git, version

As detailed in [How can I find out what version of git I'm running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475958/how-can-i-find-out-what-version-of-git-im-running) you can get the git version via

```
$ git version
git version 2.30.0
```

But it looks like this is meant to be consumed by humans, not programs. Is that correct? If so is there a "plumbing" `git version` command that can be used for numerical comparisons of the version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the source code. There is a comment about keeping the format of `git version` stable so it is safe to parse it.

```
void get_version_info(struct strbuf *buf, int show_build_options)
{
    /*
     * The format of this string should be kept stable for compatibility
     * with external projects that rely on the output of "git version".
     *
     * Always show the version, even if other options are given.
     */
    strbuf_addf(buf, "git version %s\n", git_version_string);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Piping?

```sh
git --version | awk '{print $3}'
```

Comment: I was asking if it is *safe* to do this, not *how* to parse that specific value (that bit is trivial).

Comment: You asked for "plumbing" and numeric comparisons, you did not ask for API stability...

Comment: That's what "plumbing" commands *are*. They're stable commands that can't be used programmatically. API stability is a prerequisite of running commands programmatically. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain